# UINavigationController is null after going back

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having troubles with an `UINavigationController` which `viewControllers` property is `null` after tapping *Back* on a previously pushed view controller.

The root view controller in `AppDelegate` is defined with that code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    StartViewController *startVc = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:startVc];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

At `StartViewController` I'm hiding the navigation bar within `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` where I've also a `UIButton` instance where I push the next view controller when tapping with that code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    PhilosophyViewController *philsophyVc = [[PhilosophyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhilosophyViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:philsophyVc animated:YES];
}
```

I'm heading over to the next view as expected. But when tapping the *Back* button at the navigation bar, the previous view (`StartViewController`) is empty and when checking the `viewControllers` property of the navigation controller - it is null?

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the back button connected up to an IBAction?, if so, what is the code you are using to move back?

Comment: I would also recommend checking the value of the `self.navigationController` after going back. Just because `self.navigationController.viewControllers` is `nil` does not necessarily mean that `navigationController` is *not* nil.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, so the problem must be elsewhere. Are you using a storyboard at all, or only xibs? Also, where are you checking the viewControllers property?

Comment: @Jeely The back button is currently not connected to an IBAction.
@CraigOtis I've to check that.
@rdelmar Only xibs - no storyboard. I'm checking the property at ``viewWillLoad`` in ``StartViewController`` code.

Comment: I tried also the code from @Jeely for heading back. The view itself is empty but the title in the navigation bar is here.

Answer (score 0):

The back button of the pushed viewController can be hooked up to an IBAction

```
 -(IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender{

 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

This should pop you back to the previous view controller front the stack.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm heading back to StartViewController - but the view is also empty :-(.